# Codeigniter Form-Validation: Validate if input is equals to a certain string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just need a validation on how to check if user input is equals to a certain string.

```
public function check_input()
{
   $input_str = $this->input->post("input_str", TRUE);

   $this->form_validation->set_rules("input_str, "Input String", "trim|required| validate if $input_str is equals to the string 'FOO' ");

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
       // if input_str != 'FOO', do something
   }
   else
   {
       // do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a `callback function` and then check if the value is equal to `'foo'` or not, you'll also need to change the `case` to lower so that if user writes uppercase it doesn't pose any error. I've written a possible solution for your problem, comments are mentioned wherever necessary. See if it helps you.

```
public function check_input(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("input_str", "Input String", "trim|required|callback__checkstring"); // call to a function named _checkstring

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

        // if input_str != 'FOO', do something
    }
    else{

        // do something
    }
}

function _checkstring(){

    $input_str = strtolower($this->input->post("input_str", TRUE)); // get the post data and convert it to lowercase

    if($input_str !== 'foo'){

        $this->form_validation->set_message('_checkstring','Please enter the correct value!');  //set message to the callbacked function(ie _checkstring) not the input field here.
        return FALSE;

    }else{

        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to filter the word, and

```
public function username_check($str)
{
    if ($str == 'test')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The {field} field can not be the word "test"');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

and call it in your set_rules

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
```

For more information you can check the documentation page
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods